# I cant open my bitcoin wallet

Tags: wallet

After a few days I have inserted my external hard drive where I have installed the wallet with my btc to update it.

Giving the .exe "Bitcoin-qt" would normally directly open my wallet and start loading.

Today, however, when I click on it, the initial message jumps, from where I would like to create my wallet for the first time ...

What I can do ?

[image]

As I can see, I also keep all the files:
- blocks
chainstate
- wallets
- .lock
- peers.dat
- mempool.dat

Also inform that I recently updated windows 10, I do not know if it would have influenced

Comment: Can you describe in more detail exactly what is happening, perhaps including screenshots? "the initial message jumps" is not clear at all.

Comment: Hello friend. 
I will describe my situation to you.

Whenever I access my external hard drive, where I have the btcs stored, I simply click on "bitcoincore-qt.exe" and my wallet opens directly and starts updating.

This time the problem is that my wallet does not open and I get the message like when you click for the first time to create a new one. I attach the picture on the open post.

Comment: @PieterWuille can u see it ? :)

Comment: That seems like you just don't have a wallet; if you had one before you should restore from a backup.

Comment: Did the drive-letter, assigned to the external drive, change?

Answer (score 0):

You are using bitcoin CORE with the default folder in appdata?

so the location of the entire data folder (including the complete blockchain, and wallet.dat (where your private keys are) is in:

%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin

copy and paste all that in a folder inside the USB drive.

specially care with wallet.dat, save it into TWO different drives, not one!, never do CUT and paste, do always copy and paste, and don't drag n drop either it's dangerous specially with touchpads hehe, if you don't have two usb hard drives for the entire blockchain, do a full backup in your USB drive, and then save in a flash drive only the wallet.dat.

it is one thing to have to download the entire blockchain because your USB hard drive died, and another is loosing all your bitcoins so, wallet.dat , TWO copies (remember, copies means that the file is in your computer AND on the devices) the more the better.

RESTORE: (my way, maybe there are other options, this is how i did it, multiple times! when defender screwed my blockchain data folder)

install bitcoin core (ideally the same version!, but it could be older, it works)

RUN IT
once it says sincronizing, close it.
(this is so the wallet will create the data folders)

now go to:
%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin

and delete everything inside, and replace it with your copy from your USB drive backup